# Next.js 13 project references path aliases throwing webpack error

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, tsconfig-paths

I'm migrating a small and old react project (and its nestjs server) to Next.js 13. I'm doing that by scaffolding from a CLI called [Create T3 App](https://create.t3.gg/). I use project references a lot, in all projects I work on and I'm trying to do that here like this:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["../../../../libs/core/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../../../../libs/core/" }
  ],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

But it keeps throwing this webpack loader error:

> error - ../../../../libs/core/src/path/to/file.ts
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:12) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

There are no errors marked red on the file, vscode's intellisense works fine.

I have tried adding the aliases to webpack, like so:

**next.config.mjs:**

```
// @ts-check
/**
 * Run `build` or `dev` with `SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION` to skip env validation.
 * This is especially useful for Docker builds.
 */
!process.env.SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION && (await import("./src/env/server.mjs"));
import path from 'path';

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }) => {
    return {
      ...config, 
      resolve: { 
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@core': path.resolve('../../../../libs/core/src'),
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
export default config;
```

This yielded no changes to the error message.

I have tried adding ts-loader to webpack but it throws errors in other parts of the app. I'd like to solve this without using babel if at all possible.

Does anyone know how to make paths aliases for external projects work on Next.js 13?

---

**ANSWER BREAKDOWN:**

Using the package that [@Yilmaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10262805/yilmaz) suggested, called [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) I was able to make the project references and their aliases work. This solution requires "baseUrl" and "paths" fields to be correctly set on `tsconfig.json` and these additions to `next.config.mjs`:

```
import transpile from 'next-transpile-modules';

const withModules = transpile([
  '../../../../libs/core'
]);

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  ...
};

export default withModules(config);
```

Comment: Note that [Next.js is not compatible TypeScript Project References](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8708).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your tsconfig.json does not meet default next13 `typescript` configuration. I created a next app with --typescript and this is the default `tsconfig.json`. I did not touch it

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

If you follow [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) npm package and set it next.config.js

```
import transpile from 'next-transpile-modules';

const withModules = transpile([
  '../../../../libs/core'
]);

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  ...
};

export default withModules(config);
```

Comment: I changed the tsconfig to that plus the "baseUrl", "paths" and "references" and it still shows the same error.

Comment: I htink `"../../../../libs/core/src/*"` is not correct

Comment: it is an external library project, used in many other projects, exactly the same way that I'm trying to use here. the only difference is that this is the only nextjs project.

Comment: I see now. did you try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules

Comment: that package actually worked. I'll add an edit to my question showing how my `next.config.mjs` ended up as and you can create an answer pointing to my edit and I'll mark it as the correct answer. thanks man.

Comment: Note: [`next-transpile-modules` has been deprecated](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/releases/tag/the-end). Next.js v13.1 comes with built-in support for transpiling modules.